# DynamoDb re-using ScalableTarget for multiple tables using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I am trying to add autoscaling to multiple DDB tables, since all the tables would have the same traffic pattern the autoscaling configuration for them would be identical. 
I know of a way to do that by creating ScalableTargets for each table, but since I want all tables to use the same configuration I was wondering if it is possible to re-use the scalable targets

```
  WriteCapacityScalableTarget:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 30
      MinCapacity: 5
      ResourceId:
        Fn::Join:
          - /
          - - table
            - Ref: FooTable
      RoleARN:
        Fn::GetAtt: DynamoDBAutoScalingRole.Arn
      ScalableDimension: "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits"
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb

  WriteScalingPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WriteAutoScalingPolicy
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId:
        Ref: WriteCapacityScalableTarget
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        TargetValue: 80 
        ScaleInCooldown: 10 
        ScaleOutCooldown: 10 
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization

  DynamoDBAutoScalingRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'dynamodb:DescribeTable'
                  - 'dynamodb:UpdateTable'
                  - 'cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm'
                  - 'cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms'
                  - 'cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics'
                  - 'cloudwatch:SetAlarmState'
                  - 'cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms'
                Resource: "*"
```

This works fine to enable autoscaling on a single table but when I try the same with multiple tables it fails, I am trying this like -

```
  WriteCapacityScalableTarget:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 30
      MinCapacity: 5
      ResourceId:
        Fn::Join:
          - /
          - - table
            - Ref: FooTable
            - table 
            - Ref: BarTable
      RoleARN:
        Fn::GetAtt: DynamoDBAutoScalingRole.Arn
      ScalableDimension: "dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits"
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
```

The above target fails to create, we can re-use the scalable targets for indexes in a same way but is it also possible for multiple tables?
If yes, how to achieve that?